# PaintDrawable background for TextView not visible

Tags: android, drawable

I am trying to make programatically a PaintDrawable background for a TextView so it can have rounded bottom corners. Here is the code:

```
View head = findViewById(R.id.ibTitle);
PaintDrawable bkgrnd = new PaintDrawable(R.color.Red);
((PaintDrawable) bkgrnd).setCornerRadii(new float [] {0,0, 0,0, 6,6, 6,6});
head.setBackgroundDrawable((PaintDrawable) bkgrnd);
```

ibTitle is a TextView.

The problem is that there is no indication of any change to its background, color or corners.

I must be missing something simple. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make round corners in xml also and then only set the background from resource
like setbackground from resource R.drawable.mydrawable

where mygdawable can be something like:

```
<stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#ff000000"
        />

<padding android:left="1dp"
         android:top="1dp"
         android:right="1dp"
         android:bottom="1dp"
         /> 

<corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
 android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. But I want to be working with a PaintDrawable I can re-program.

Comment: Lukap,I came back and tried your approach and have decided that it is the simplest way to accomplish what I need. I found that I could set the background either through head.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bkgrnd);

Comment: or by setting android:background="@drawable.bkgrnd in the layout xml that defined the TextView. For the bkgrnd.xml I used:          <shape ...
  android:shape="rectangle">
 <corners 
  android:bottomRightRadius="8dp" 
  android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp" 
   android:topLeftRadius="0dp" 
   android:topRightRadius="0dp"
   />     
    </shape>

Answer (score 0):

Did you do head.invalidate() somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I tried that both before the the bkgrnd was declared and after setBackgroundDrawable. There was no change, no indication the code was executed.